# Deep Learning VM: How to free RAM?

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, gcp-ai-platform-notebook, google-dl-platform

I'm brand new to GCP and Deep Learning VM. I got it to train some deep learning models. While training in the google cloud jupyter notebook it crashed as it could not copy input tensor from GPU to CPU: specifically:

```
InternalError: Failed copying input tensor from /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 in order to run TensorDataset: Dst tensor is not initialized. [Op:TensorDataset]
```

After looking into it , it occurs when theres not enough memory in the GPU. I check my memory and my RAM was 95% full after just running for like an hour after I initialized the VM. I have no idea how this happened. How can I free up this memory?

Comment: r u using a custom train loop? use keras `fit` function so u dont have to worry about memory management

Comment: @datdinhquoc, No, using default model.fit(). I'm training like 100 models, but in a for loop so only the result is stored, not the model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found out that the memory in the GPU was still present even after the python script terminated. Run `nvidia-smi` to see if there is a python process taking up GPU memory, and if so run `pkill -9 python` to kill all associated memory and processes for python.